# D3 Bullet Chart Add additional text to markers that isn't the data placing them

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, qlikview

I'm using the D3 Bullet Chart from stefan walther  [1]: https://github.com/stefanwalther/qvD3BulletCharts as a starting point to write an extension from qlikview to fit a specific purpose using the D3 javascript library and style.css - I've added additional markers to represent grade boundaries and they are placed on the diagram based on the data from Qlik. My problem is I want to append additional text / wrap text to represent what grades the markers are e.g. you got 93 and you were 3 marks off an A mark. I've written a simple array that hold the grades and I'm trying to append them in the following code -

```
    var gradeData = ["A*", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];

            var marker = g.selectAll("line.marker")
             .data(markerz);

                 marker.enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "marker")
                .attr("x1", x0)
                .attr("x2", x0)
                .attr("y1", height / 6)
                .attr("y2", height * 5 / 6)
                .attr("fill", "red")
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("x1", x1)
                .attr("x2", x1);

                 marker.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("x1", x1)
                .attr("x2", x1)
                .attr("y1", height / 6)
                .attr("y2", height * 5 / 6);

            var markerLabel = g.selectAll("text.marker")
            .data(markerz);

           markerLabel.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return gradeData[i];})
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .attr("dx", "1em")
            .text(String)
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("x", reverse ? function(d) { return w0(d) + x0(d); } : w0)
            .attr("y", height / 3);

             markerLabel.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("x", reverse ? function(d) { return w1(d) + x1(d); } : w1);
```

Nothing is showing up. Maybe you can help me understand where I've gone wrong.  Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi, I think it's hard to answer based on your question. Please elaborate a bit more, especially please clarify what's not showing up? The extension itself?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay in replying, I didn't realise I had a reply! I can't append text to a marker - so the extension and marker appears but not the text. Is it not possible to append text to markers using the d3 library?